# Use object in multiple forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

Currently I'm making an asp.net webapplication. I've a login form where I make an object for the user. How can I access this object in another form?

Please see my code:

**Login form**

```
 users user = new users(username, password);
 user.receiveUserInformation();
```

**Form to userpage**

This is where I want to acces the object "user".
What's the right way to do this. I thought something like this:

```
  users user = new users(username, password);
  user.receiveUserInformation();
  Session["new"] = user;
```

And then:

```
Session["new"].receiveUserInformation();
```

But that obviously doesn't work.

Comment: Are you building webforms or MVC application?

Comment: It's a webforms application. But it works now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will work using session :
Just cast it back to users class

```
users newUser = (users) Session["new"];
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, how can I give the parameters username,password through the constructor in this way? Something like this?: users user = (users)Session["new"](username, password);

Comment: No, thats not possible, you are creating a new instance if thats the case. whats the purpose in instantiating again?

Comment: aaah yesyes I understand it works now thankyou! But is it save to store passwords (encrypted) in a session?

Comment: if encrypted, yes its ok but you should architect your system well to avoid/minimize storing passwords

Answer (score 1):

Once put your object instance in the Session collection you could retrieve it and reassign a new  users instance.

```
if(Session["new"] != null)
{
    users user = Session["new"] as users;
    if(user != null) user.receiveUserInformation();
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i would create an instance at the top of each page for the user class

```
users user
{
    get
    {
        return Session["new"] as users;
    }
    set
    {
        Session["new"] = value;
    }
}
```

then from anywhere within that page you can call it like this:

```
if(user!=null)
{
     //do stuff with user   
}
```

if you don't want to do this for every page, you can create a base class and put the instance there and then inherit that class to all of your pages

```
public class MyBase : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    users user
    {
        get
        {
            return Session["new"] as users;
        }
        set
        {
            Session["new"] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

then for every page:

```
public partial class Page1: MyBase
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         if(user != null)
         {

         }
    }
}

public partial class Page2: MyBase
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         if(user != null)
         {

         }
    }
}
```

in your login page you just have to initialize the session after you validate username and redirect whatever page they need to see